# MSVC chokes in forward class template declaration

Tags: c++, templates, visual-c++

MSVC fails to compile

```cpp
#include <iostream>

template<int N, int = N>
struct A;

template<int, int V>
struct A{static constexpr int VALUE = V;};

int main() {
  A<1> a;
  std::cout << a.VALUE;
}
```

with `(3): error C2065: 'N': unknown identifier`
`(10): error C2975: 'V': invalid template argument 'A', constant expression expected` (roughly translated).

**clang** compiles it silently.

So, the question: rotten code or demented MSVC?

MSVC version = **VS 2019**.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the shown code. No comment on the mental state of MSVC.

Comment: Small variations makes the code compile [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/LmVYGb).

Comment: @Jarod42 Tried your edit and it worked. But I'm still having a hard time understanding why MSVC screams when omitting the parameter name.

Comment: Other problematic variation [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/fpDsdb). msvc seems to have problem to *"collapse"* declarations. It even compiles invalid code [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/RIYndD).

Comment: Definitively msvc bug.

Answer (score 1):

It was a bug in MSVC manifested up to compiler version 19.22, and fixed in 19.23. Demo: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/occvKEfc3